# extjs treestore with proxy

Tags: extjs, store, models, treepanel

I'm creating a MVC extjs application. I've got a treepanel with a store, which is loading the data from a php source.
I get the following json-formatted response:

```
[
{
    "text": "Home",
    "leaf": true,
    "dbName": "NULL",
    "children": []
},
{
    "text": "Moje Firma s.r.o.",
    "leaf": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Vydane",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo"
        },
        {
            "text": "Prijate",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "Já Živnostník",
    "leaf": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Vydane",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_de"
        },
        {
            "text": "Prijate",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_de"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "Nezisková organizace",
    "leaf": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Vydane",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_neziskova"
        },
        {
            "text": "Prijate",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_neziskova"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "Příspěvková organizace",
    "leaf": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Vydane",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_prispevkovka"
        },
        {
            "text": "Prijate",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_prispevkovka"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "Moje Firma SK s.r.o.",
    "leaf": false,
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Vydane",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_sk"
        },
        {
            "text": "Prijate",
            "leaf": true,
            "dbName": "demo_sk"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

My store:

```
Ext.define('Statistics.store.Menu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model: 'Menu',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,

proxy   : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url  : 'data.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}


});
```

And model:

```
Ext.define('Statistics.model.Menu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'leaf', type: 'boolean'},
    {name: 'expanded', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false},
    {name: 'dbName', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'NULL'}
],

});
```

This configuration works, when the data are saved in a .json file. But id doesn't work, when they are loaded from a php source.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server response must look like this:

```
{
   success: true,
   children: // here is the array of items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your field says db_name and json response says 'dbName'.  Is it a typo can you check?

Comment: thanks for reply.
it was a mistake, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the data coming from different domain/ any proxy that is redirecting the request?  Just try changing proxy type to 'jsonp' and see to rule out any doubts.