# ExtJS tree dynamically load

Tags: javascript, extjs

i create a ExtJS tree by loading data dynamically, the js code is below

```
var treeModel = Ext.define("TreeModel", {
extend : "Ext.data.Model",
fields : [{id: "id", type : "string"},
          {name : "text", type : "string"},
          {name : "leaf", type : "boolean"}]
});



var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({ 
    model: 'treeModel', 
    proxy: { 
        type: 'ajax',  
        url: 'listtreecontent.action' 
    }, 
    root: { 
        expanded: true 
    },
    reader: { 
            type: 'JSON',
            root: 'array' 
        },
    autoLoad:true 
}); 

var treePanel = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({ 
    title: 'Data management', 

    width: 500, 
    height: 300, 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 

    useArrows: true, 
    rootVisible: false, 

    store: store

});
```

but it does not show the tree

i can get the response data,
[response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYb99.png)

when i write the response data into a json file, and let the url = jsonfile address, it can show the tree, i do not know why?

Comment: Did you check your DevTools console?. Were there any errors?

Comment: i think this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952140/extjs-treestore-with-proxy

Comment: my return is a type of string  that contains 
    {"success":true,"children":[]}
but it also do not work.
and i also try the type of jsonobject ,it does not work

Answer (score 0):

maybe in the struts2, we should set a param for the action

```
<action name="listtreecontent" class="org.easygeoc.account.ListTreeContent" method="returnTreeNodes">
<result type="json">
<param name="root">array</param>
<param name="root">js</param> 
</result>
</action>
```